# Angular2 testing error when using templateUrl

Tags: unit-testing, angular, testing

I am writing some tests for my Angular2 application according to the documentation but I have run into a problem which I can't seem to fix. I get the following error when trying to launch the spec runner:

```
Failed: This test module uses the component CategoriesComponent which is using a "templateUrl", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.
```

I understand this is happening as I am using a seperate template file for the template within the component but I jhave tried multilpe solutions which don't seem to work.

Here is my component under test:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'categories-component',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/catalog/categories/categories-dashboard.html',
    moduleId: module.id
})

export class CategoriesComponent {
    title: 'Categories;
}
```

The categories-dashboard.html file:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

and my testing module for the component:

```
import {TestBed, ComponentFixture, ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, async} from "@angular/core/testing";
import { By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { CategoriesComponent } from "../../../../components/catalog/categories/CategoriesComponent";
import { DebugElement } from "@angular/core";

let comp:    CategoriesComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<CategoriesComponent>;
let de:      DebugElement;
let el:      HTMLElement;

describe('BannerComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ CategoriesComponent ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }
            ]
        });

        TestBed.compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CategoriesComponent);

        comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

        // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
        el = de.nativeElement;

    }));

    it('should display original title', () => {
        expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
    });
});
```

I have tried to implement TestBed.compileComponents() into into the component but wherever I put it it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone see why this error is occurring or point me in the directoin of a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compileComponents` resolves asynchronously (as it makes an XHR for the template), so it returns a promise. You should handle anything requiring the resolution of the promise, inside of the `then` callback of the promise

```
TestBed.compileComponents().then(() =>{
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CategoriesComponent);

    comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

    // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
});
```

Comment: Great. That solved my issue but has thrown up a new one! Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL. I will investigate